# Read bag file from GCP bucket python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bag

I have a bag file that I need to apply transformation in python and upload it to another bucket. I'm finding some difficulties to read the bag file in my python script. There's any solution for that?

Comment: there's a library for handling bag files. [bagpy](https://jmscslgroup.github.io/bagpy/)

Comment: But I have always to download it right?

Comment: Yes. You *could* mount the buckets to the filesystem using [GCS Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) but this would increase the costs as GCS Fuse does more calls than you would need in this scenario. Doing a simple download to local filesystem, perform whatever transformation you need, and upload the resulting bag to the other bucket is the fastest and cheapest way to do it.

Comment: Great! If I do it with Cloud Functions is the same thing right?

Comment: yeah, GCF uses an ephemeral file system (eg. temporary) but for your usecase this doesn't matter. Depending on the time it takes to download/transform/upload you might need to change the default timeout as described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) though, as the default maximum execution time for a GCF is 1 minute...